# Is there a term for the "ever longer, implicitly hyphenated-like groupings" in contemporary English?

Tags: terminology, linguistics, contemporary-english

There was just a question here about a phrase which had

> *adjective* and then *a long complex phrase* as the noun

This is a real feature of "contemporary" English usage - I guess the best way to describe it is:

> using ever-longer, ever-more-complicated phrases "as single words" and sticking all sorts of modifiers on them.

(The same applies to every sort of modifier - verbs, nouns, anything.)

5 or 10 years ago I would have said "business English" is going this way, but it's now just taken over basically "English usage".

My question, do linguists (or, uhh - whoever) have a term for this sort of thing? for this aspect of contemporary English?

Lawrence below uses the phrase **"that 'German' sentence-in-a-word thing**" to describe it, and that is spot on.

Surely, linguists/academics/someone has an actual term for this extremely pervasive, ubiquitous, movement in contemporary English?

---

the two answers thus far are excellent, but I'm not sure if they really capture the sense, **fat bounty coming!**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve. FWIW, the full OED has its first citation for ***preparedness*** as 1590, so it's hardly a "contemporary" phenomenon.

Comment: @Lawrence yes that is precisely correct.  Absolutely.  **"the 'German' sentence-in-a-word phenomenon"**.   Surely, linguists/academics/someone has a actual term for this movement in contrmporary English ?

Comment: It's called 'business-speak' but English isn't (in my view) being 'taken over by it'. It's confined to executive and managerial circles in the business world and it is not highly regarded by the truly literate.

Comment: hmm @NigelJ ...  it is one feature of business-speak (as is - say - "acronyms"), perhaps ?

Comment: This question is about the use of complex and compound words to replace phrases, yet the close votes list early uses of "preparedness" as a reason to close. Clearly, I'm missing something.

Comment: hi @Davo, I happened to mention (one of millions of) examples, which included that word.  Very confusingly, folks started discussing/explaining **that particular phrase** which I had just mentioned as an example.

Comment: I find it amusing that people who are objecting to compound neologisms say "business-speak."

Comment: jeff - glad you got the humour.  Also, "that German sentence-in-a-word thing" is one of those  "that German sentence-in-a-word things"

Comment: Why didn't you provide an example? Do you think everyone will know what you're on about? I only bumped into the *pediatric terrorist and disaster preparedness* question the other day. Examples of this growing phenomenon, please! P.S "Lawrence below" has deleted their comment.

Answer (score 2):

"Agglutination" is a technical term for the practice and is a longstanding feature of Germanic languages including English: "seaworthy," "witchcraft," "footwear," "underwear," "seventeen," "eyesore," "landscape," "seascape," "blacksmith," "doorway," "roadside," etc.

Notice that these words are generally formed from Germanic roots and are relatively short, usually two or three syllables.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will explain to my *self-identifying, gluten-intolerant* friends that they are, in fact, contributing to the agglutination of western culture.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a noun string, I believe (among copyeditors, if not among linguists).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_string